# Maintain navigation history in WebView

Tags: android-webview

In my app I have main activity and child activities. An action on main activity opens a child activity. Each child activity loads web page that have various urls all pointing to server locations.
I am able to navigate to all the urls but when I press back, I am not redirected to the previous page. Instead it exists and brings me to main activity. The back button action should navigate to last url location. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add each url to a List object and then use that object to navigate back.

```
private LinkedList<String> navigationHistory;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    ....
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (navigationHistory.size() > 0) // Check if the url is empty
    {
        navigationHistory.removeLast(); // Remove the last url

        if (navigationHistory.size() > 0) {
            // Load the last page
            mWebView.loadUrl(navigationHistory.getLast());
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if (!navigationHistory.contains(url)) // Check for duplicate urls
            navigationHistory.add(url); // add each loading url to List
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not working for me.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check. You need to add each loading url to List.